# SendMessage doesn't launch function (HoloLens/Unity/C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, hololens-emulator

**Goal:** Changing from one scene to another using auditive controls.

**Problem:** When launching the application in the HoloLens Emulator, the first scene opens. When saying "Next Step", the HoloLens does recognize the sentence, but the sendMessage doesn't open the `OnNextStep()` function.

Thanks for trying to help! :)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Windows.Speech;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class KeywordManager : MonoBehaviour {

    KeywordRecognizer keywordRecognizer = null;
    Dictionary<string, System.Action> keywords = new Dictionary<string, System.Action>();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        keywords.Add("Next Step", () =>
        {
            SendMessage("OnNextStep", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
        });

        // Tell the KeywordRecognizer about our keywords.
        keywordRecognizer = new KeywordRecognizer(keywords.Keys.ToArray());

        // Register a callback for the KeywordRecognizer and start recognizing!
        keywordRecognizer.OnPhraseRecognized += KeywordRecognizer_OnPhraseRecognized;
        keywordRecognizer.Start();
    }

    private void KeywordRecognizer_OnPhraseRecognized(PhraseRecognizedEventArgs args)
    {
        System.Action keywordAction;
        if(keywords.TryGetValue(args.text, out keywordAction))
        {
            keywordAction.Invoke();
        }
    }

    void OnNextstep()
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log(this);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("FirstStepScene");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Comment: 1.Post your code not screenshot. 2.Use `UnityEngine.Debug.Log` not `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`. With Debug.Log you can now tell us which function is not working properly. tell us if `OnNextstep` is being called at-all.

Comment: Code has been added. OnNextStep is NOT called.

Comment: You also don't need `SendMessage` here. You can just invoke the method directly: `keywords.Add("Next Step", () =>
        {
            OnNextStep();
        });` Whiiich would have the side effect of pointing out that the method name didn't match exactly. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unity's [`SendMessage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html) function is case sensitive when it comes to calling functions.

Your function name is `OnNextstep` but you are calling `OnNextStep`:

```
SendMessage("OnNextStep", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
```

Notice the capitalized and non capitalized **"S"**. Fix that and your problem should be fixed assuming there is other hidden problems.

**Note**:

Avoid using `SendMessage` in Unity. If you want to call a function from another script, use `GameObject.Find` to find the *GameObject* then `GetComponent` to get that script then call its function. You can also use [events and delegates](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/events) to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and your advice. I have roughly 4 weeks to create HoloLens software to visualize a repair process and we never studied anything Unity nor HoloLens nor 3D modelling. So your help is very much appreciated. I'll put you on the credits list of my project :D

Comment: You are welcome. If this is a school project, don't wait for the teacher, go online and start learning. Many information on Unity' [website](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials).